# Partitioning tests across multiple nodes with Gradle and TestNG

Tags: java, testing, gradle, continuous-integration, testng

I have a java project with a lot of tests.  My build is using Gradle and tests are using TestNG and invoked by gradle.  I would like to speed up testing a build by running my build simultaneously on multiple workers and having each worker run only a subset of the tests.

Each node will provide 2 environment variables `TOTAL_NODES` and `NODE_NUMBER`, where `TOTAL_NODES` is the number of nodes running my build and `NODE_NUMBER` is the number assigned to this particular node.

I want a way of partitioning the tests so that each node runs ~ 1/TOTAL_NODES tests and each test is run exactly once.  Is there a simple way of doing this with gradle and TestNG?

I could manually divide tests into even groups by labeling each one in a specific group, but there are many tests and that's a major maintenance hassle, plus it doesn't scale if the number of nodes change.

Gradle offers tests filtering, but it seems like it's all based on class name matching, and can't accept arbitrary filtering functions.  I could find all the test files and then subdivide them according to some hashing scheme before plugging them into a test filter, but it seems needlessly complex.

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no simple way provided by Gradle or TestNG, but you can implement Listener `org.testng.IMethodInterceptor` and in it implement algorithm for splitting.

`org.testng.IMethodInterceptor#intercept` is called before test suite starts and you get all test instances which are scheduled for run. So if you read your ENV variables and then spit all instances to some categories based on `TOTAL_NODES` you can return only category which matches `NODE_NUMBER` e.g. using `HashMap` where key is `NODE_NUMBER` and value is `List<IMethodInstance>` at the end `intercept()` returns `map.get(NODE_NUMBER)`

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors

Comment: Thank you!  That sounds like exactly what I need.  I was trying to figure out a gradle pre-test hook that would help but I hadn't thought to look in testNG itself.  I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go, but I've encountered an error I don't understand.  I get NPE when I filter the tests using IMethodIntercepter.  I started a ticket about it here https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/690.

Comment: Yes, looks like bug in some tool. Did you try to use latest Gradle/TestNG versions or on the other hand some older versions? In fact I implemented similar solution earlier and it works for me so probably problem is in (internal) integration between Gradle - TestNG (maybe version depending).